# Reading CSV files and saving it into objects/lists

Tags: c#, csv

`DateTime,2048,2049,2050,2051
23/07/2015 8:57:30 AM,0,-30972,-31049,-21068
23/07/2015 8:57:32 AM,0,-30970,-31047,-21066
23/07/2015 8:57:35 AM,0,-30967,-31044,-21063
23/07/2015 8:57:37 AM,0,-30965,-31042,-21061
23/07/2015 8:57:40 AM,0,-30962,-31039,-21058
23/07/2015 8:57:43 AM,0,-30960,-31036,-21055
23/07/2015 8:57:45 AM,0,-30957,-31034,-21053
23/07/2015 8:57:52 AM,0,-30949,-31026,-21045
23/07/2015 8:57:55 AM,0,-30947,-31024,-21043`

Hello, I am trying to save each column into the concurrent dictionary.

I have a concurrent dictionary.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, int[]> fileLoading = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int[]>();
```

I want to try to save each column header as the keys, and I want to save all the values in the column into the int array.

The column head are not fixed because the headers do change to different values.

In addition I want to save the date/time into a list as well.

```
List<string[]> timeCol = new List<string[]>();
```

After that is done, I want to display it into a chart using the dictionary because I need to do some operations on them prior displaying, with the datetime in the first column.

```
List<string[]> rows = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToList();
DataTable loadedValues = new DataTable();
        ConcurrentDictionary<int, int[]> fileLoading = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int[]>();

        rows.ForEach(x =>
        {
            try 
            { 
                loadedValues.Rows.Add(x);


            }
            catch { Console.WriteLine("Value not compatable"); }
        });
```

This is what I have so far but this is only saving into a datatable which I want to a concurrent dictionary list instead to do some certain operations.
Thank you

Comment: That's nice... Care to share some code? This isn't a "Here's what I want, please do it for me site." We're here to help you through the issues. It's not a "code it for me for free service"

Comment: I'd do like that: read each line then split by comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Here is an example of how you can iterate through the parsed rows to fill a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

```
// Parse
var rows = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Select(l => l.Split(',')).ToArray();

ConcurrentDictionary<int, int[]> fileLoading = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int[]>();

// Iterate through each column (skipping the date column)
for (int c = 1; c < rows[0].Length; c++)
{  
    // Column header
    int column = Int32.Parse(rows[0][c]);

    // Column values
    fileLoading[column] = rows.Skip(1).Select(r => Int32.Parse(r[c])).ToArray();
}
```